# Highlight button before the function ends in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, function, button, highlight

I will try to explain my problem as clear as I can. 
I have a piano that you can play and record the song what you do, and every button of the piano that you play, this button is highlighted. The problem is that I have another button to play the song that I have recorded, but what I want is to Highlight every button of the piano that is sounding. 
Here is a part of the function I've coded:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender
{   
    for(NSString *string in [Singleton sharedInstance].notesMusicals)
        if([string isEqualToString:@"doMenor"]){
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"do-menor_ON.png"];
            [doMenorButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
            CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
            soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,(CFStringRef) @"Do_m", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
            UInt32 soundID;
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
            //doMenorButton.highlighted = YES;
             sleep(1);

        }
        else if([string isEqualToString:@"Re"]){
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"do-menor_OFF.png"];
            [doMenorButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"re_ON.png"];
            [reButton setImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
            CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
            soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,(CFStringRef) @"Re", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
            UInt32 soundID;
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
            sleep(1);

        }
```

You can see that in every note, I highlight the button of that note, but the problem I have is that the button is only highlighted once the function ends, so all my notes will be highlighted once the melody has finished.
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to call your highlightning code in a separate thread with

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:_myParamsArray];
```

For example:

```
...
        else if([string isEqualToString:@"Re"]){
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(highlight:) withObject:myButton];
            CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
            CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
            soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,(CFStringRef) @"Re", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
            UInt32 soundID;
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
            sleep(1);

        }

...

-(void) highlight:(UIButton)*button
{
                UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"re_ON.png"];
                [button setImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Please excuse if there are any typos in the code. I modified it right here in the editor.

You'll need to modify me example in order to deactive other highlighted buttons but that should be no problem

Comment: UI elements must only be updated on the main thread, not on a background thread. So this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `sleep(1)` call. The user interface elements will only be updated when the `play` function returns to the main runloop.

Using this synchronous method for timing is a bad design. You could for example use `NSTimer` to wait asynchronously for one second. But that requires a major redesign of your `play` method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have some kind of timer object (see `NSTimer`) to sync up with the music and then highlight the buttons as needed (make sure you use the main thread for this).

Doing this will not affect the button currently being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I did not try to compile it so many typos etc):

```
// Assumes ARC. Note that since the block retains "self", you won't get dealloc'd
// until the queued block has run. If the user wants to stop the music set "cancel = YES"

@implementation MyClass
{
    NSArray *notes;
    NSUInteger theNote;
    BOOL cancel;
}

- (void)playOneSound
{
    if(cancel) return;

    if([string isEqualToString:@"doMenor"]){
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"do-menor_ON.png"];
        [doMenorButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,(CFStringRef) @"Do_m", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
        //doMenorButton.highlighted = YES;
    }
    else if([string isEqualToString:@"Re"]){
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"do-menor_OFF.png"];
        [doMenorButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"re_ON.png"];
        [reButton setImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,(CFStringRef) @"Re", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
    // now going to queue up another sound to play in 1 second, leaving your UI responsive
    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self playOneSound];} );
}

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
    notes = [Singleton sharedInstance].notesMusicals;
    theNote = 0;
    cancel = NO;
    // by defering til the next runLoop round, the play button gets to unhilite
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self playOneSound];} );
}
```